# Ignore Issue-Type in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, issue-tracking

i have a little problem with xcode4.
i get issues in my projects with this type of code:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
  }
  return self;
}
```

[image]

i know i could fix it with something like:

```
- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
  }
  return self;
}
```

or

```
- (id)init {
  self = [self init];
  if (self) {
  }
  return self;
}
```

but the problem is, that i use a massive amount of external libraries in a special project and i don't want to edit this files, push an update to github or something else.

so is there a option to deactivate this type of notification/issue posting in xcode?

Comment: What does the warning say? I am not getting a warning with this code. I think of assignments within if clauses as code smells.

Comment: it says `Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses` . Yeah i also don't like this style. but the third-party lib does use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options as far as I know:

- Switch to GCC as compiler, as LLVM checks for this warning by default, GCC doesn't
- Add `-Wno-idiomatic-parentheses` to LLVM compiler Warnings / Other Warning Flags

[Clang's Options to Control Error and Warning Messages](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cl_diagnostics)

[image]

Comment: i use GCC. trying to use `-Wno-idiomatic-parentheses` on GCC throws an error `cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-idiomatic-parentheses"`

Comment: @choise, nah this is a clang/LLVM specific flag, won't work in GCC. Funny that you get the error with GCC. Are you sure every subproject is set to compiler with GCC? I've just tried with GCC 4.2 and no warning for this case.

Comment: Switching to LLVM 2.0 is no option? Are you sure that compiler setting is not overriden by a target? I suggest creating a simple app template app and try the different compilers with the init code and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: still no luck. will give it a try again tomorrow =/

Comment: unable to do this with my project. in very target and built setting for the project i'm using gcc 4.2. i'll accept your answer, because i think it's the right one. probably xcode4 is still a bit buggy. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if(self == [super init])` not `if(self = [super init])`. `=` is used for add a value to a variable, `==` is meaning `Is equal`?